# Client application exception in java

Tags: java, distributed, corba

I want to run an CORBA Application using java on two machines.When I  run this app on one machine there is no troubl, and I can see the "Hello World!" string on cmd screen.But when I try to run it on two machines I faced an exception.

[image] 
while I have a HelloClient.class in my related directory!
The commands that I used to compiling and running this application are:
On the client machine:

```
idlj -fall Hello.idl  //to mapping the Hello.idl to java
javac *.java HelloApp\*.java  //to compile the all .java files such as                HelloClient,Hello,Hellostub,HelloHelper,HelloHolder,HelloOperation and HelloPOA.
```

On server machine:

```
javac *.java  //to compile HelloServer and HelloImpl classes.
srart orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost 192.168.138.134  //to start Object Request Broker Daemon
start java HelloServer -ORBInitialPort 1050  //to start HelloServer
```

On client machine:

```
java HelloClient -ORBInitialHost 192.168.138.134  //to run the Hello application client.
```

but when I run this application in one machine I can get the output correctly.
[image]

Comment: Where is your ClientApp? Do you have a class HelloClient in a default package?

Comment: My HelloClient,Hello,Hellostub,HelloHelper,HelloHolder,HelloOperation and HelloPOA classes are in HelloApp package and the HelloClent class is copmiled individually in no package. I use the classes which are implemented in this tutorial.[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/idl/jidlExample.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the `HelloClient` in the directory where `HelloClient.class` resides OR you have to set the classpath to the directory via `java -cp <dirname> HelloClient`